# (Swift iOS) Storing Article Content (image/paragraphs) locally

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8

I'm planning out a sort of reference book application. For each topic there will be a page with an image and text stored. I don't want to create new views in xcode for each page since there are 100+ topics, I'd rather find the easiest way to store the items in a database and then call the content to display on a view template when the user selects the topic from a list. After searching around I see that this is potentially done with Core Data or SQLite, and maybe even json, but I have not encountered a clear answer.

What's the best way to handle this sort of data?

Comment: Yes, you are correct that you would not create a new view for each page of content.  It sounds like you're right at the beginning of learning iOS development, the best way to learn is to get started. I think you'll find that this problem will solve itself as you learn more about object oriented programming, the model view controller design pattern, and ios development. I'd suggest following a tutorial like this one: https://teamtreehouse.com/learn-swift to get a sense of what iOS development is like before you start on your reference book project.

Comment: I'm halfway through a course but most of the material has been computational. I'll keep moving forward and hopefully they'll cover this properly.

Comment: Given that you are new, I would recommend using MagicalRecord. Its a wrapper on top of Core Data and provides a cleaner, easier to use syntax for common operations etc

Answer (score -1):

You should create a database in Core Data and where you'd like to store images, use the response from [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial) (conversion to Swift is left as an exercise for the reader) and store the `fileName` as a string.

Don't use json to store 100+ items, it will be very slow. SQL is quite fast, even though it's a mobile device.

Comment: That linked answer uses NSData to download images? Thats quite possibly the laziest and worst recommendation. NSURLSession or AFNetworking would be a better recommendation... But that aside the OP is specifically referring to Core Data